# SSIS - MySQL source: Could not create a managed connection manager

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2012, ssis

I'm using VS 2012 with SQL Server Data Tools installed. I have an ADO NET Source, which uses the .Net Providers\MySQL Data Provider and am trying to push some data to an OLE DB Destination, which uses a normal SQL Server Native Client 11.0 provider. Everything seems ok, I can preview data from the source and columns are mapped well - but when I run the project I get the following error:

```
[ADO NET Source [2]] Error: ADO NET Source has failed to acquire the connection {47479EC0-98BC-4664-A8F9-0FF0278969FD} with the following error message: "Could not create a managed connection manager.". 
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: ADO NET Source failed validation and returned error code 0xC0208449.
```

Most Google hits talk about setting the Run64BitRuntime to false. Mine is greyed out and defaulted to false already. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using an ODBC connection and was able to follow this post step by step to get an alternative route working:
[SSIS MySQL Copying Table to SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451190/ssis-mysql-copying-table-to-sql-server)