# SSIS Package Failure

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a package that extract data from MySQL source. I am using ADO NET source to get the data. The target tables is SQL SERVER 2012.
The package is running OK each hour with sql server agent.
The package fails randomly (every few days).

this is the error:

```
Error: 2013-12-15 20:11:24.90
   Code: 0xC0208449
   Source: source1 ADO NET source1 [71]
   Description: ADO NET Source has failed to acquire the connection {C2F3842B-D6F2-4D88-841E-3D19356730DE}
 with the following error message: "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior 
to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.".
End Error
Error: 2013-12-15 20:11:24.90
   Code: 0xC0047017
   Source: source1 SSIS.Pipeline
   Description: ADO NET source1 failed validation and returned error code 0xC0208449.
```

all the sources and targets at the package has unlimited timeout (commandSQL set to 0). so it's weird that the package failed on timeout.
I'm not sure about the part of the validation.
Do you have any idea what to do? or why it's happening?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Actually I think the MySQL tag was incorrect as he is talking about SSIS.

Comment: Ignore the reference to "validation", that's just the execution phase when ADO NET is trying (and failing) to get a connection to MySQL. Check out these [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086066/ssis-mysql-source-could-not-create-a-managed-connection-manager) [links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451190/ssis-mysql-copying-table-to-sql-server). These people are having somewhat different problems, but it sounds like using an ODBC provider to talk to MySQL works better than ADO NET in general. You might want to give that a try.

Comment: I think ADO NET is fine, if you look at SSIS blog they suggest ADO Net, microsoft till recently didnot like ODBC :) [See this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/03/04/connecting-to-mysql-from-ssis.aspx)